# Why can't I access an ID value inside an IF statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make script which allows only devices with equal IP address as code but I can't make it with if statement. When I write `x.id` inside the statement it doesn't work... Ideas?

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=DisplayIP";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    };
    function DisplayIP(response) {
        var x = document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = response.ip;
    }
</script>
</head>
<p id=ipaddress></p>
<form name="login">
<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="check ip">
</form>

<script language="javascript">
function check()
{
 if(x.id == "22.333.444.555")
  {
    window.open('ipadressok.html')
  }
 else
 {
   alert("ip adress unknown")
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Local variables are only accessible *in the scope (eg. function) they are defined*.

Comment: @user2864740 Even still, `x.id` wouldn't resolve, since x itself would be the id value, it was never defined as an object with an `id` property.

Comment: @mhodges `id` would resolve.. just not usefully. It is indeed another issue.

Comment: @user2864740 Technically, yes. It would be `undefined`. I meant it wouldn't resolve to the value the OP is looking for

Comment: You  forgot the quotes around your ID in the HTML code: `<p id="ipaddress">`

Comment: Why are you doing this on the client side? Do you actually think this js code considered as a proper validation to stop other devices from accessing that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the getIPAddress function.

When you fire the check function you can assign the value to x.

This is needed because x is not a global variable and will not be defined if referenced before being declared in the scope of the check function.

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=DisplayIP";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
};

function DisplayIP(response) {
    document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = response.ip;
}

// Add this function here to retrieve the value of the ipAddress element.
function getIPAddress() {
    return document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML;
}

function check() {
    // Declaring and assigning x in here
    var x = getIPAddress();
    
    if (x == "22.333.444.555") {
        window.open('ipadressok.html')
    } else {
        alert("ip adress unknown")
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id=ipaddress></p>
<form name="login">
    <input type="button" onclick="check()" value="check ip">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: now need x.id replace with only x and it work correctly, thanks !